# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency (function defined in context)

Tags: react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

I am getting the error:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setSelectedPage'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
const Blah = props => {
    const { setPage } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPage("new project");
    }, []);

    return (
        <NewProjectState>
            <Index props={props} />
        </NewProjectState>
    );
};

export default Blah;
```

I understand that react would like me to define the `setPage` function in `useEffect` however it is obviously used elsewhere. I did wonder why not simply put the `setPage` function within the return function. I guess what i'm asking is what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Whats the reason for you not wanting to put ```setPage``` dependency in your dependency array

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure it won't affect your application in bad ways, then you can ignore the linter with `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

```
const Blah = props => { 
  const { setPage } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage("new project");
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <NewProjectState>
        <Index props={props} />
    </NewProjectState>
  );
};

export default Blah;
```